# How many counting operations are for matrix exponential?

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

Let A be a m x m matrix and

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{A^k}{k!}$$

I have this following flops count:

1. For $A^k$, $(n-1)(2m^3-m^2)$ flops
2. $n$ multiplications for $k!$
3. $n$ divisions for $\frac{A^k}{k!}$
4. $n-1$ additions for the summation

So the total is $(3n - 1) + (n-1)(2m^3-m^2)$ flops. Is it correct?

Comment: You might want to use the Horner scheme $I+A(I+A/2(I+A/3(...(I+A/n)...)))$, it should not change the count too much. But note that the divisions and matrix additions are element-wise, also in your step 3 and 4.

Comment: @LutzL same for the additions in the step 4.

Comment: @LutzL what are the implications if the divisions and matrix additions are element-wise?

Comment: You have to multiply the previous count by $m^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's slow down a bit and count summand by summand:
\begin{array}{lll}
\mbox{summand} & \mbox{multiplications required, using prev. results} & \mbox{some prev. results}\\ \hline
{1 \over 2!} A^2 & 1 + m^3 + m^2 & \\ \\
{1 \over 3!} A^3 & 1 + m^3 + m^2 \; \mbox{(as $A^3 = A^2 A$, i.e., $m^3$ multiplications)} & {1 \over 2!}, \; A^2 \\ \\
{1 \over 4!} A^4 & 1 + m^3 + m^2 \; \mbox{(as $A^4 = A^3 A$, i.e., $m^3$ multiplications)} & {1 \over 3!}, \; A^3 \\ \\
\end{array}
Am I missing something?

Comment: So $\frac{1}{k!}A^k = \frac{1}{k}A \times (\frac{1}{(k-1)!}A^{k-1})$??

Comment: Yes.  The matrix commutes with itself and with all scalars, right?  So, we can save a lot of computations by re-using previously computed results.

Comment: does this affect the flop count though?

Comment: It means, once you have $A^{k-1}$, you can get $A^k$ by performing just one matrix multiplication ($m^3$ flops).